# crop large image taken from camera to 640x640pixel

Tags: android, camera, crop

I have checked many discussion but i can't seem to find an answer. How can i crop and large image taken by a camera and crop it to a 640x640 pixel size? Im returning a `URI`

EDIT: I would like to allow the user to crop the image!

Comment: Are you capturing image from camera using intent?

Comment: yes i am. MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Answer (score 0):

use the below code

You can use this link also for your reference

Click [Crop image using rectengle](http://www.londatiga.net/featured-articles/how-to-select-and-crop-image-on-android/)!

```js
int targetWidth = 640;
int targetHeight = 640;
Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
    targetWidth, targetHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
Path path = new Path();
path.addRect(rectf, Path.Direction.CW);
canvas.clipPath(path);
canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap,
    new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight()),
    new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), null);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
imageView.setImageBitmap(targetBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use the createScaledBitmap people use to create thumbnails.

```
    byte[] imageData = null;

    try     
    {

        final int THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 64;

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);

        imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, false);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        imageData = baos.toByteArray();

    }
    catch(Exception ex) {

    }
```

Your bitmap imageBitmap would probably have to come directly from your camera instead of a file, but the general idea stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
private Bitmap crop(Bitmap src, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap dst = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dst);
    canvas.drawBitmap(src, new Rect(0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight()),
                           new Rect(x, y, width, height), null);
    return dst;
}
```

Type arguments are self explanatory.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, using the `intent` object:

```
 intent.setType("image/*");
 intent.putExtra("outputX", int_Height_crop);
 intent.putExtra("outputY", int_Width_crop);
 intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
 intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
 intent.putExtra("scale", true);
```